# How can I write a query in SQL Server on XML column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
table tbl_event_log

columnName DataType
id          Int
event       XML
userinfo    XML
```

and data should be in event is

```
<Event><Player readName="9.Make You Talk!" demoName="Video Game" **portal="FB"** totalDuration="0:07/0:07(100%)" /></Event>
```

and i want to write query to get data from portal="FB"

Comment: Can you give better explanation as what you need and how your XML looks like? Your expected output?

Comment: expected output is like this
 id userInfo event
1204462 null <Event><Player readName="9.Make You Talk!" demoName="Video Game" portal="FB" totalDuration="0:07/0:07(100%)" /></Event>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `nodes()` method to split your rows and then get values:
Check this solution and hope it helps you:

```
Declare @mytable table (id int,event xml,userinfo varchar(200))

Insert into @mytable
select 1, '<Event><Player readName="9.Make You Talk!" demoName="Video Game" portal="FB" totalDuration="0:07/0:07(100%)" /></Event>','Test'
Union
select 2, '<Event><Player readName="9.Make You Talk!" demoName="Video Game" portal="TW" totalDuration="0:07/0:07(100%)" /></Event>','Test'



select
    s.id,
    e.p.value('@portal', 'varchar(max)') as portal
from @mytable as s
    outer apply s.event.nodes('Event/Player') as e(p)

select * from (
select
    s.id,
    e.p.value('@portal', 'varchar(max)') as portal
from @mytable as s
    outer apply s.event.nodes('Event/Player') as e(p)
) Test
where Test.portal = 'FB'
```

**Attn:** Replace @mytable with your table name.

**Note**: Event column in your table must be XML datatype.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data into specific fields you could extract them directly from the xml.

For example:

```
select id, userinfo,
event.value('/Event[1]/Player[@portal="FB"][1]/@readName','varchar(max)') as readNameFB,
event.value('/Event[1]/Player[@portal="FB"][1]/@demoName','varchar(max)') as demoNameFB,
event.value('/Event[1]/Player[@portal="FB"][1]/@totalDuration','varchar(30)') as totalDurationFB
from tbl_event_log;
```

[@portal="FB"] : only get the Player tags where the portal="FB"
[1] : use the first one